# IO6 doesn't call -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I have some views in my app that I don't want to suport orientation.
In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I add navigation:

```
...
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
...
```

In each `ViewController` I have `UITabBar` (I don't know if this is important).

In the first view controller I add:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
        return NO;
    }

    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
```

`supportedInterfaceOrientations` is called at the view loading but `shouldAutorotate` doesn't call as I rotate device.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12893485/550177 does that help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because neither `UITabBarcontroller` nor `UINavigationController` is passing shouldAutorotate to its visible view controller. To fix that you may subclass either UITabBarController or UINavigationController and forward shouldAutorotate from there:

In your subclassed UITabBarController add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
}
```

In your subclassed UINavigationController add:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me what do you mean by "subclass UINavigationController", I know make a class that inherits from UINavigationController but what to do with it, where to load it when I make it?

Comment: To subclass it create new class and call it `MyNavigationController` (make sure it's superclass is set to `UINavigationController`). In that newly created class add method `shouldAutorotate` which I mentioned earlier. Do the same for your `UITabBarController`. You should simply use it like: `MyNavigationController *nav = [[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];`. Similary for your new `MyUITabBarController`. If you are using interface builder then simply set Class attribute there to be pointing to your new class.

Comment: Ok, I have made custom navigation controller and add shouldAutoRotate in it. There is no selectedViewController only presentedViewController. I don't need to subclass UITabBarController because I use only UITabBarView in each view. But now rotation doesn't work anywhere. So how to enable it in some view if I did all right.

Comment: For `UINavigationController` you should use `visibleViewController` as in my reply.  Did you try with debugger, is `shouldAutorotate` called in your custom `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 0):

in the `AppDelegate`:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window  // iOS 6
{

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;


}
```

in your ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```