# How to set two of the screens in Portrait mode and another two screen in Landscape on iPhone?

Tags: ios

I have a `homeViewController` (should always be in portrait mode) , which has four buttons to be redirected to a tar bar controller, which has four different viewController (first, second, third, fourth).

We want to have `firstViewController` and `fourthViewController` in portrait mode always. And `secondViewController` and `thirdViewController` in landscape mode always, also when we will go back to `homeViewController` form any of these viewControllers the `homeViewController` should always be in portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -shouldAutrotate - Method of the ViewControllers to make sure they dont rotate when the device does. Just return NO, and the VC will always be displayed like your xib-file or storyboard specifies.
Heres the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW124

and heres an example:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}
```

EDIT: In Response to your coment:

UITabBarControllers wont forward the shouldAutorotate - Value to the ChildViewControllers. (As a sidenote, neither will a NavigationController). Your best bet is to subclass The TabBarController. Heres a link to a Stackoverflow-Post describing this. Have fun.
[IO6 doesn't call -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996293/io6-doesnt-call-boolshouldautorotate)

Comment: When I use shouldAutorotate with presentViewController it works. But when I use UITabBarController in which I have all my four view, it does not. Thanks in advance

Comment: @KuldeepBhimte - i need clarification: you mean when you transition manually (in code) it works, but when you transition with a segue from the TabBarController it doesn't? is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I have used shouldAutorotate method with both (while allocating view controllers with presentViewController and UITabBarController) Nut with presentViewController it orientation works properly and with tab bar it doesnot..