# IOS setting orientation not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, landscape, portrait

As the title describes I am having a big problem with the orientation in my app atm. It seems I can't get the control over the orientation at all in the different slides. The following things have I tried and works/not works in my app:

- Xcode refuse listen to any code given in the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method at any slide.
- Xcode refuse listen to any settings given in the stoaryboad for each slide.
- Xcode listens to info-plist file, but from this file you can only set orientation for all Views/slides in the app. I want some slides to allow landscape-mode and others portrait-mode only.

I have tried to remove all UINavigationBars/Tabbars in my app and actualy only use 1 single ViewController as initial ViewController and the problem still occurs, can only manage orientation from info-plist file. Basicly the app resufses to listen to anything other then the info-plist file adjusting the orientation settings?

I have tried my best to understand the problem but I can not say I have gained any bigger "aha moment" so far since all possible ways apple offers to adjust the settings simply doesnt work in my app atleast, great apple!.... Do we have anyone else who experienced this before or has heard of the problem before?

Answer (score 2):

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is deprecated in iOS 6.

You should override the `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` method of your UIViewController subclass.

Example:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

**Edit:**

If you're using a UINavigationController, you must subclass that as well, and implement the logic above. This is expected functionality. Relevant StackOverflow Q/A:

[iOS 6 bug: supportedInterfaceOrientations not called when nav controller used as window root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12893485/314042)

[iOS 6 rotations: supportedInterfaceOrientations doesn´t work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12411651/314042)

[Set different supportedInterfaceOrientations for different UIViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12602243/314042)

Comment: - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
} Didn't work, still landscape is possible even if using this code....

Comment: Are you using a UINavigationController?

Comment: also only the root view controller or full screen presented view controllers get these messages.

Comment: Yes I am using a UINavigationController

Comment: See edit and relevant SO posts. If you're using a UINavigationController, you must subclass it and implement the aforementioned method.

Comment: You also need to make sure that the supported interface orientations are listed in your info.plist